# Cambiar ancho de un div cuando se elimina otro

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo tres divs con posicionamiento flex, cada uno ocupa el 33% del ancho, lo que quiero es que cuando uno de ellos se elimine los otros dos pasen a ocupar el 50% cada uno y cuando uno de los dos que queda se elimine que el restante pase a ocupar el 100% pero no tengo ni idea de como puedo hacer esto ya sea con css o javascript.

Dejo un ejemplo cutre de lo que quiero hacer, es con paint pero no se me ocurría otra de explicarlo:
[image: Ejemplo de lo que quiero conseguir]

Si pudieseis resolverme la duda os lo agredecería.

```css
body {
height: 20vh;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.div {
    width: 32%;
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 1vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div">Texto1</div>
    <div class="div">Texto2</div>
    <div class="div">Texto3</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dejas un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer, pero pordrías también dejar código de lo que has intentado? o Simplemente quieres que alguien te de el ejercicio resuelto

Comment: Código de lo que has intentado, ¿quieres hacerlo con CSS o con JavaScript?, ¿qué tecnologías usas? me falta tanta información que estoy por redireccionarte [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Lo primero no es ningún ejercicio, simplemente estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta y me ha surgido esta duda, lo único que he hecho es posicionar con flex al 33% pero no se como puedo conseguir el redimensionamiento. Estoy trabajando con React y extraigo los datos que conforman los divs de una API, por lo que cuando me faltan datos no debo pintarlos y los divs deben redimensionarse

Comment: ¿Podrías facilitar una estructura HTML y el CSS de lo que estás intentando? Puedes editar tu pregunta para añadirlo. Si facilitas código ejecutable aumentarás las probabilidades de que alguien se interese por tu problema, lo reproduzca y te aporte una solución.

Comment: Hecho, ahora espero que sea más fácil de entender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con **flexbox** podemos especificar los fragmentos de la fila que queremos que ocupe cada columna. Al dar a las columnas `flex: 1` estamos diciendo que queremos que cada columna se reparta el espacio de la fila a partes iguales.

Al haber 3 columnas cada columna ocupará 1/3 del espacio de la fila. Si se borra 1 de las columnas y quedan 2 de ellas, pasarán a ocupar 1/2 del espacio. Si queremos pasar a tener una sola columna, esta ocupará 1/1.

```css
.fila {
  display: flex;
}

.columna {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>Con 3 columnas</p>
<div class="fila">
  <div class="columna"></div>
  <div class="columna"></div>
  <div class="columna"></div>
</div>

<p>Cuando se borre una, con 2 columnas</p>
<div class="fila">
  <div class="columna"></div>
  <div class="columna"></div>
</div>

<p>Cuando pasemos a tener 1 sola columna</p>
<div class="fila">
  <div class="columna"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Justo era lo que necesitaba, mil gracias :D